# Sass import incorrect directory

Tags: sass, webpack

I have the following heirarchy:

```
main.scss
styles/_partial.scss
fonts/
```

In `main.scss`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova';
    src: url('./fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf');
}
```

The import here causes no problems. However in `styles/_partial.scss` I have:

```
@import '../main';
```

This causes a problem. Apparently what's happening is that `_partial.scss` is importing `main.scss`, but when it tries to import the font, it looks in `styles/fonts/..` (`partial.scss` current directory) and not main.scss current directory.

I'm using Webpack and this is the error I get:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/app/styles/_partial.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf in /src/app/styles
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd import partials into `main.scss`, not the other way round. Main would have `@import 'styles/partial.scss';` (note: no underscore here).
Then also the font url will work, because the path is relative to the base file `main.scss`.